# STUFF function to display multiple columns with comma-separated in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to display a table column (assume 2 columns) values with comma-separated in the output

```
col1    Col2    
================
xyz       abc  
pqr       uvw
```

Output needed:

```
Col1      Col2
========  =======
xyz,pqr    abc,uvw
```

I tried below query but not sure how to include col2 to the below query and make it as a single query:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(t.Col1 AS VARCHAR(MAX))
           FROM Table_1 t
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: `STUFF` isn't what does the "magic", it's `FOR XML PATH`. All `STUFF` does is removes the leading comma (`,`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a0db0/11)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table MyTable(ColA varchar(max),ColB varchar(max))
INSERT INTO MyTable(ColA,ColB)VALUES('xyz','abc')
INSERT INTO MyTable(ColA,ColB)VALUES('pqr','uvw')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT STUFF((select  ',' + cast(t.ColA as varchar(max))
from MyTable t
for xml path ('')
), 1, 1, '') AS ColA,
STUFF((select  ',' + cast(t.ColB as varchar(max))
from MyTable t
for xml path ('')
), 1, 1, '') AS ColB
```

**Query 2** :

```
 SELECT 
       STRING_AGG(colA, ',') AS colA,
       STRING_AGG(colB, ',') AS colB
    FROM MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a0db0/11/0)**:

```
|    ColA |    ColB |
|---------|---------|
| xyz,pqr | abc,uvw |
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible approach:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   col1 nvarchar(50),
   col2 nvarchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (col1, col2)
VALUES
   (N'xyz', N'abc'),
   (N'pqr', N'uvw')
```

Statment:

```
SELECT 
   Col1 = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', col1) FROM Data FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''),
   Col2 = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', col2) FROM Data FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Result:

```
Col1    Col2
xyz,pqr abc,uvw
```

Notes:
If you use SQL Server 2017+, you may use `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT 
   STRING_AGG(col1, N',') AS col1,
   STRING_AGG(col2, N',') AS col2
FROM Data
```

Comment: Zhorov, yes this will work. And you are using "from Data" two times (one for Col1 and another for Col2). how to include the col2 in single query without again including "from Data" for 2nd time for your same query.

Comment: @MaheshMohan Couldn't you use `STRING_AGG()`?

Comment: im using SQL server 2014. its doesn't support string_agg() function.

Comment: @MaheshMohan `FOR XML` clause returns the results from one SELECT statement as `XML` with all columns in it.