# STUFF function to display multiple columns output values in quotes SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

STUFF function multiple column output values in quotes

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(t.Col1 AS VARCHAR(MAX))
           FROM Table_1 t
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Needed output :

```
col1
-----------------
'abc',xyz','pqr'
```

how to include quotes('') for each value in the output like above for above query.

Comment: Isn't this your last question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656495/stuff-function-to-display-multiple-columns-with-comma-separated-in-sql-server

Comment: And `STUFF` still isn't what's doing the work. Do you understand the solutions you were given? What have you tried to quote the values? Why didn't it work? If you don't understand the solutions then you should be asking to understand it. if you do you should easily be able to add the quotes to the values.

Comment: Also, if you are using SQL Server 2017 or later, then please just use `STRING_AGG`, which offers a much more humane way of doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STUFF function to display multiple columns with comma-separated in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656495/stuff-function-to-display-multiple-columns-with-comma-separated-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',''' + CAST(t.Col1 AS VARCHAR(MAX))+''''
FROM Table_1  t
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: PeterHe Works like a charm. Could you explain what '.value ' line of code would do. It would help me to understand.

Comment: value is the xquery function. It retrieves the text value, which can be encoded for special characters,  in the xml. Without it, the xml is casted to string directly and encoded characters will not be decoded