# Concatenate query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, for-xml-path, sql-query-store

I have two tables one containing the details of the user and another containing the details of user's tasks. I need to return one row for each user containing the username and the task ids.
The query I have is as follows

```
select 
    w.user
    , (select '; ' +taskid from tasks d where d.guid = w.guid  FOR XML PATH(''))
from taskuser w
where w.type = 'pm0'
group by w.user, w.tid
```

The output I am getting is

| username | TaskId |
| --- | --- |
| Frane | PM0-10003 |
| Jordan | PM0-10004 |
| Jordan | PM0-10005 |
| Jordan | PM0-10006 |

What I want is

| Username | TaskId |
| --- | --- |
| Frane | PM0-10003 |
| Jordan | PM0-10004, PM0-10005, PM0-10006 |

Comment: `group by w.user, w.tid` should be `group by w.user`. And you XML sub-query needs to pull all tasks for a user, so probably a different where clause.

Comment: Your current approach works but it will create a leading delimiter (i.e. you'll get `, PM0-10004, PM0-10005, PM0-10006`).

If you want to avoid that I suggest using the `STRING_AGG` built-in function (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))

Comment: First group data by user, tid then use stuff with XML path function then you will be able to do that. Just google stuff with XML path you will get an easy solution. or refer this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656495/stuff-function-to-display-multiple-columns-with-comma-separated-in-sql-server)